# Dynamic Change *ngIf State with Function Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

```
 <ion-col sizeLg="4" size="12" *ngFor="let item of category.menu_items">
   <ion-badge (click)="follow(item)" *ngIf="followcontrol(item.id)">Follow</ion-badge>
 </ion-col>
```

When the page opening it's work correctly. When click this button `followcontrol()` function result will change. My `follow()` function:

```
 follow(item) {
    
    this.request.postFollowed(item)
    
    this.following(); // This is for succesfull message
  }
```

`followcontrol()` :

```
    followcontrol(id){
    return this.request.getFollowByID(this.followsdata, id) // this function control the data and return a boolean value.
  }
```

How can i get the currently value of `followcontrol()` after `follow()` function worked?

Comment: you shouldn't use functions in html as binding

Comment: I use the button in a *ngFor loop. Is there any option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the ids into an array (ids):

```
ids: number[] = []; 
follows: boolean[] = [];   

ngOnInit() {
  this.your_service.getCategory().subscribe(category => {
    category.menu_items.forEach((item, index) => {
      this.ids[index] = item.id;
      this.followcontrol(item.id, index);
    }
  });    
}

followcontrol(id, index) {
  this.request.getFollowById(this.followsdata, id).subscribe(value => {
    this.follows[index] = value;
  });
}
```

in your template:

```
<ion-col sizeLg="4" size="12" *ngFor="let item of category.menu_items; let i = index">
   <ion-badge (click)="follow(item)" *ngIf="follows[i]">Follow</ion-badge>
 </ion-col>
```

So, You'll avoid to use methods inside of your template (which emit side effects), and you have all data prepared from the initialization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When i click the "Follow" it still show. Is there any way to re-render the button when `follow()` function work?

Comment: This my fault. I forgot refresh the follow list. But really thank you my code more optimized thanks to you.